# Licensing in Docker containers

Tags: docker, dockerfile, licensing, docker-image

How does the licensing of a software/program work in a Docker container?
For instance; say I am installing a signing utility in a docker container.
This utility signs my files. (You can actually consider a program which needs license to run; which is installed in a container).
The license has to be installed in my local machine.

How will this work?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but you're able to mount files from your host machine to your docker container using the -v option when starting the container. Hope it helps/is relevant.

Comment: Imagine you have an "Enterprise Software" that can run on docker, but uses an old-fashioned licensing validation model that requires files or - nightmare! - license files issued for a given machine name? I guess that's what OP asked for

Answer (score 0):

**This is a very general case and as such does not concern Docker or its licence**, but the specific application you want to run inside the container and its licence.

IMO the answer should always be found in the licence records of a specific application.